# Laravel Factory data not adding the data as JSON to the DB

Tags: json, laravel, database

i am trying to Seed the following data into db using laravel factory seeder.

```
[{"type":"cta","data": {"title":"NxtPress.org","subtext":"Welcome to NxtPress.org || Managed with \u2665 by Nxt Invent Solutions","buttontext":"Visit Website","buttonurl":"https:\/\/nxtinvent.com","linktype":"_BLANK"}}]
```

but this is added with ("") double inverted comma into db.

here is my factory code.

```
public function definition(): array
{
    return [
        'title' => 'Home',
        'slug' => '/',
        'layout' => 'default',
        'blocks' => '[{"type":"cta","data": {"title":"NxtPress.org","subtext":"Welcome to NxtPress.org || Managed with \u2665 by Nxt Invent Solutions","buttontext":"Visit Website","buttonurl":"https:\/\/nxtinvent.com","linktype":"_BLANK"}}]',
    ];
}
```

Here is my database seeder code

```
ModelsPage::factory(1)->create();
```

the data should be save as it is without the "" commas on it.

Comment: are you using ``casts - json => array`` in model? and fillable?

Comment: @Sumitkumar  This Model is created by the Filament Fabricator Plugin.